# Сохранение структуры БД в XML

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, entity-framework

Возникла надобность получить структуру БД и сохранить её в файл XML, не смог найти решения, . Можно ли как-нибудь через entityframework это сделать или может источник с решением есть

Comment: Используйте INFORMATION_SCHEMA - это стандарт ANSI, набор вьюх с информацией о базе данных. Обычными sql-запросами извлекаете нужную информацию.

Comment: Entity Framework тут ничем не поможет. Для его использования придётся создать набор классов, совпадающий с INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Это возможно, но вряд ли оправдано.

Comment: Можно, но готовых средств вы вряд-ли найдете. Как минимум потому что любую базу можно сдампить нативными средствами *SQL сервера и скопировать дамп куда нужно. Смысла сериализовать это в какой-либо другой формат нет никакого.

Comment: Либо, если это жизненно необходимо, то посмотрите, что можно сделать сериализацией объектов в XML.

Comment: Уточните: вам нужно получить именно **структуру** (имена таблиц, имена и типы столбцов) или **данные**?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov,структуру ДБ, без данных

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а если с помощью select выбрать все таблицы в бд и for xml, xmlschema получить что то,это не структура бд получится?

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-the-information_schema-database/

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да сделал так же, спасибо! осталось только xml файл на диске сохранить через запрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте INFORMATION_SCHEMA - это стандарт ANSI, набор вьюх с информацией о базе данных. Обычными sql-запросами извлекаете нужную информацию.

Ваша задача решается простейшим кодом.

```
private string _connectionString = @"...";
```

```
string sql = "select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES for xml auto";

using var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
conn.Open();
using var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
string resultXml = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Console.WriteLine(resultXml);
File.WriteAllText("db schema.xml", resultXml);
```

Тут главная сложность написать sql-запрос, который будет возвращать необходимые данные.

---

Entity Framework тут ничем не поможет. Для его использования придётся создать набор классов, совпадающий с INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Это возможно, но вряд ли оправданно.

---

Для чего вы сохраняете схему? Вероятно, для того, чтобы по ней можно было воспроизвести новую БД с аналогичной структурой.
Вы постоянно упоминаете Entity Framework в своих вопросах, значит работаете именно с ним. Значит, нужно просто использовать *миграции*. Они как раз и предназначены для того, чтобы воспроизводить структуру БД.
Файлы миграций уже хранятся в вашем проекте, так что никаких дополнительных действий не нужно.

Когда нужно воспроизвести БД с аналогичной структурой на другом компьютере, то применяют миграции: [Applying Migrations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).
Недавно был введён новый способ с помощью бандлов: [Introducing DevOps-friendly EF Core Migration Bundles](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-devops-friendly-ef-core-migration-bundles/).